# I have to check the condition if both condition are true then its 1 else 0 in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have to check if the `value` are `less equal 100` and `"fl1":1` `then`  `"fl2": 1` `else :0`. please check the expected output.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value": 100,
             "fl" :1
        },
        {
            "value": 300,
             "fl" :0
        },
        {
            "value": 14,
             "fl" :0
        },
        {
            "value": 3
             "fl" :0
        },
        {
            "value": 30,
             "fl" :1
        },
        {
            "value": 60,
             "fl" :1
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected Output :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value": 100,
             "fl" :1,
             "fl2":1
        },
        {
            "value": 300,
             "fl" :0,
             "fl2":0
        },
        {
            "value": 14,
             "fl" :0,
             "fl2":0
        },
        {
            "value": 3
             "fl" :0,
             "fl2":0
        },
        {
            "value": 30,
             "fl" :1,
             "fl2":1
        },
        {
            "value": 60,
             "fl" :1,
             "fl2":1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- map on data
- if `value<100` AND `fl=1` => use merge to addfield `fl2:1`
- else use merge to addfield `fl2:0`

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IHhLsy-v3gc)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "data": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$data",
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "$lte": [
                      "$$m.value",
                      100
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$m.fl",
                      1
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$m",
                  {
                    "fl2": 1
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$m",
                  {
                    "fl2": 0
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "as": "m"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: and if we have to make duplication of the object `fl` how we can do that? [Anotherquestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69305232/make-duplication-of-key-and-value-in-mongodb) did you get my point?