# make duplication of key and value in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Explanation: How we can make a duplication of the field `f1`.  I want to introduce the replica of the object `f1` that name as `f2`, see the expected output

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value": 100,
             "fl" :1
        },
        {
            "value": 300,
             "fl" :0
        },
        {
            "value": 14,
             "fl" :0
        },
        {
            "value": 3
             "fl" :0
        },
        {
            "value": 30,
             "fl" :1
        },
        {
            "value": 60,
             "fl" :1
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output

```
{
   "data": [
       {
           "value": 100,
            "fl" :1,
            "f2" :1
       },
       {
           "value": 300,
            "fl" :0,
            "f2" :0
       },
       {
           "value": 14,
            "fl" :0,
            "f2" :0
       },
       {
           "value": 3,
            "fl" :0,
            "f2" :0
       },
       {
           "value": 30,
            "fl" :1,
            "f2" :1
       },
       {
           "value": 60,
            "fl" :1,
            "f2" :1,
       }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- its similar with the previous here without condition, read `$map` documentation, you will be able to do all those

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/965kFeeC01E)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "data": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$data",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$m",
              {
                "f2": "$$m.fl"
              }
            ]
          },
          "as": "m"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```